# IndexTank - How to prioritize result of a query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, full-text-indexing, indextank

Using the `indextank` rubygem, if I index a post like this

```
indexes.document(post.id).add({:title=> post.title, :text=> post.body})
```

What should my query look like such that the `title` matches are returned before the `body` matches. Doing this:

```
indexes.search("title:#{query} OR text:#{query}", :snippet=> :text)
```

returns all matches ordered from newest to oldest.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your scoring function 0 defined as?  By default, it is "-age", which means most recent first.  For text relevance, you can replace scoring function with "rel", which means text relevance.

I don't know of a way to ensure that every title match is guaranteed to be above the rest, but you can "boost" the title greatly by adding "^10" to your title part of the query. Here's an example:

`title:potter^10 text:whatever`

This means title matches are 10 times higher than matches for the "text" field.  You can raise the number "10" higher if necessary.

Comment: Hi Chris, there could I found full documentation of IndexTank query syntax?

Comment: Hi Yaroslav, here is the IndexTank query syntax:  http://www.searchify.com/documentation/query-syntax

Comment: Thanks! I didn't mentioned this document while developing  IndexTank's API implementaion for http://indexden.com.